# Notification Transparency

Tags: 13.04, notification

Is there a way to customize the notifications (notify-send) that appear ?
Colour, transparency, font, font size, font colour, etc ?

I would mainly like to increase transparency.

Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. Just install patched version of NotifyOSD.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
pkill notify-osd
```

What You also need is NotifyOSDConfig to configure it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

Now You can specify in which area of the screen You would like notifications to show up.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd gravity 1
```

This is default option - You can also use all numbers from 1-6.

Now just run notifyosdconfig and You can change various settings - also opacity.

More information and video can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/patched-notifyosd-with-close-on-click.html .